# Django - syncdb causes error: "DatabaseError: no such table: django_site"

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenv

I recently built a dev machine to use at home, I've been spending the last couple nights trying to get it running with a development version of our website.

---

1] First off cloned the repo of our website into a local folder.

2] Then I created a virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper for the website

3] I then used the requirements.txt in the repo to install dependencies, this failed a ton of times and I ended up having to go through the requirements.txt one line at a time until I found out i needed mercurial installed for it to finish.

4] After verifying my dependencies were all installed I went to sync the db with "python manage.py syncdb" and got the error: "DatabaseError: no such table: django_site". This seems to create an empty db file in the location specified in the settings.py.

---

5] I read the other stack-overflow posts about this error and tried commenting both django.contrib.sites and django.contrib.sessions from my installed apps as that worked for some people, it has not for me.  I also tried using python manage.py migrate as I have south in my installed apps and it was mentioned in another post but no luck for me.

I believe I am doing something fundamentally wrong in this process as I was able to do it just fine at work weeks ago and that dev machine still works fine.

I'm not the most adept individual when it comes to Linux and I may have some kind of path issue or what have you. Any help would be great!

Comment: did you remove `django.contrib.sites` from `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: @karthikr Yes, this was the last thing i tried was removing both sites and sessions. Still not syncing. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: well. that is the error. the sites has dependencies on other apps in the framework. Add it, and then run syncdb

Comment: @karthikr I've already had sites in my installed apps, it still throws the same error, in fact it throws this error regardless of which apps are listed as installed apps in the settings.py.

Comment: @leotemp: Can you please post the error which you are getting and your settings.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
pip install south
```

Add south to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

And run `./manage.py syncdb`

and `./manage.py migrate`

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have south installed and in my installed apps but it still throws the same error when I try to "./manage.py syncdb"

Comment: what's your Django Version?